Date labels every month and for a selected day in each month on the chart (ggplot)
I'm preparing a chart that basically looks like this
df1 <- read.table(text = "DT   odczyt.1 odczyt.2
'2023-01-18 00:00:00'   686 1.5
'2023-02-18 23:00:00'   487 6.8
'2023-03-04 00:00:00'   498 1.5
'2023-04-20 03:00:00'   961 1.54
'2023-06-21 05:00:00'   397 1.6
'2023-08-10 19:00:00'   532 6.6
'2023-08-21 23:00:00'   493 3.8
'2023-09-19 01:00:00'   441 9.2
'2023-11-3 07:00:00'    793 8.5
'2023-12-21 13:00:00'   395 5.5", header = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate (DT = as.POSIXct(DT))

ggplot (df1) +
  geom_line(aes (x = DT, y = odczyt.1), color = "indianred") +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = "1 month",
                   minor_breaks = "2 day") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.justification = "center") 

I want to add labels on the x-axis for each 10th of the month. Is there a simple method for this? Of course, I want the remaining elements of the chart to remain.

You can create a vector of datetimes to customize the axis labels
library(tidyverse)

breaks <- as_datetime(c(seq(ymd_h('2023-01-01 12'), ymd_h('2024-01-01 12'), by = '1 month'),
                        seq(ymd_h('2023-01-01 12'), ymd_h('2024-01-01 12'), by = '1 month') + days(x = 9)))

ggplot (df1) +
  geom_line(aes (x = DT, y = odczyt.1), color = "indianred") +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = breaks, date_labels = '%Y-%m-%d',
                   date_minor_breaks = '2 days') +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.justification = "center") 


Created on 2024-04-27 with reprex v2.0.2

You can create a vector of POSIXct items for 10th of each month covered by your data, then use that in the breaks = argument.
# create the dates for the labels
my_dates <- do.call(
    make_datetime,
    setNames(
        crossing(year(min(df1$DT)):year(max(df1$DT)), 1:12, 10),
        c("year", "month", "day")
    )
)

# use this vector in breaks= parameter
ggplot (df1) +
  geom_line(aes (x = DT, y = odczyt.1), color = "indianred") +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks =my_dates,
                   minor_breaks = "2 day") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.justification = "center") 

You might need to filter the labels vector as it runs from Jan-Dec for each year of your data. If you are charting from, say, June - June, it would create extra labels.

Thank you for your response. The solution is clear. The only problem is there is no label for the first day of the month.
crossing(year(min(df1$DT)):year(max(df1$DT)), 1:12, c(1, 10)), - solves the problem, right?

OK, I misunderstood - I thought you wanted to replace the labels with labels on 10th of each month, re-reading I see you did say add. You could add a line my_dates <- c(my_dates, my_dates - lubridate::days(9)) before the ggplot() to do this. Or better yet use Seth's answer which is more concise.
